# Minimize a function with parameters with scipy

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, scipy, minimization

I want to ask how to minimize a function (The sum of square errors) with the optimization method in scipy minimize. I tried but it seems that I am not doing it good because the error and the parameters do not change from the initial values.
Here is my code:

```
def objective(p, y):
    y = np.array([98.494500, 97.828500, 97.610000, 97.314000, 97.014500, 92.959000, 96.696222])
    p = beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1, tau2
    return  (((100 * DiscountFactor('rate',np.exp(p[0] + (p[1]+ p[2]) * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4])) * p[4]/yearfractionTenors() - p[2] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4]) + p[3] * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[5])) * p[5] / yearfractionTenors() - p[3] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors() / p[5])) -1, fecha_valoracion, maturity, composition= 'linear', basis= 'act/360').result) - y) ** 2).sum()
x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1 and tau2
res = optimize.minimize(objective, x0, args = y)
print(res)
output: fun: 64.30571361326217
hess_inv: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
  jac: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
  nfev: 8
  nit: 0
  njev: 1
 status: 0
 success: True
    x: array([ 0.03, -0.03,  0.  ,  0.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ])
```

It seems that my mistake is that I am not using the input values (initial values) in the good way. I want to know if someone can help me with this issue.
Basically, I want to know how I can minimize the function by changing the parameters in the initial array. Maybe the mistake is in the objective function.
A small example of the issue:

```
def objective(p, y):
    y = np.array([98.494500, 97.828500, 97.610000, 97.314000, 97.014500, 92.959000, 96.696222])
    p = beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1, tau2
    return  (((100 * DiscountFactor('rate',np.exp(p[0] + (p[1]+ p[2]) * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4])) * p[4]/yearfractionTenors() - p[2] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4]) + p[3] * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[5])) * p[5] / yearfractionTenors() - p[3] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors() / p[5])) -1, fecha_valoracion, maturity, composition= 'linear', basis= 'act/360').result) - y) ** 2).sum()
x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1 and tau2
res = optimize.minimize(objective, x0, args = y)
print(res)
```

The discount factor function is irrelevant, but here is the class you need to run it:

```
class DiscountFactor:

def __init__(self, val_given, value, start_date, end_date, composition, basis):
    self.start_date = start_date
    self.end_date = end_date
    self.composition = composition
    self.basis = basis
    self.yf = year_fraction(start_date, end_date, basis)

    if val_given == 'rate':
        self.rate_to_df(value) 
    else:
        raise ValueError('val_given must be: rate or df' )

def rate_to_df(self, rate):
    if self.composition == 'linear':
        df = 1/( 1 + rate*self.yf)
    else:
        raise ValueError('composition must be one of the following: linear, yearly, biannual, continuous')
    self.result = df
    return self.result
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows to reproduce your input - output.

Comment: @Mr.T done it, I added the smallest way I can, sorry if it is too long but I am new here.

Comment: You should not assign `p` inside the objective function. You could use `p` to initialize vars  `beta0`… to use laters somewhere, but you neither use `beta0`….  nor define them.  You probably, should either assign `y` outside the objective function or don’t pass it as a parameter. 
Fitting usually is a multimodal problem. You should run and compare results from several initial points. I could say more if it would be possible to run the code, but there are too many undefined vars/functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Askold Ilvento, you are redefining your arguments inside the function scope. This will make optimize fail as the function will yield always the same result; it is also a bad practice and a potential source of bugs. Try:

```
def objective(p, y):
    return  (((100 * DiscountFactor('rate',np.exp(p[0] + (p[1]+ p[2]) * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4])) * p[4]/yearfractionTenors() - p[2] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[4]) + p[3] * (1 - np.exp(-yearfractionTenors()/p[5])) * p[5] / yearfractionTenors() - p[3] * np.exp(-yearfractionTenors() / p[5])) -1, fecha_valoracion, maturity, composition= 'linear', basis= 'act/360').result) - y) ** 2).sum()

x0 = np.array([0.03, -0.03, 0, 0, 1, 1]) #Initial values of beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1 and tau2
y = np.array([98.494500, 97.828500, 97.610000, 97.314000, 97.014500, 92.959000, 96.696222]) 
beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1, tau2 = optimize.minimize(objective, x0, args = y)
```